# Поменять перед и зад 3D модели в Unity

Tags: unity3d

Импортировал 3D модельку в свой проект. Импортировалось так, что направления вперёд и назад у моделки перепутаны. Таким образом dir = Vector2.up; Есть какой то простой способ поменять направления у 3D модели у Unity?

Comment: Для того, чтобы так не происходило, нужно обнулять трансформы в программе для `3D` моделинга, например в `3dmax`, `blender`, а не делать костыль в виде пустого объекта и в нем размещать кривую модель, как предлагает делать это @KingPeas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если при импорте ваш объект загрузился как то не так: pivot не там у модели расположен, или оси не совпадают потому что он загрузился в другой системе координат, то помочь вам может пустой объект, внутри которого вы размещаете ваш импортированный и выставляете его так как нужно. А в дальнейшем делаете префаб из этой конструкции и пользуетесь префабом.

Если проблема с масштабом или нормалями, то стоит посмотреть в [настройки импортера](http://docs.unity3d.com/ru/current/Manual/HOWTO-importObject.html), для этого выберите модель импортируемого объекта в проекте и посмотрите настройки, попробуйте их поизменять.

Если ничего это не помогает, то изменяйте [настройки экспорта](http://docs.unity3d.com/ru/current/Manual/HOWTO-exportFBX.html) в программе 3D-редактора.

Comment: А как именно добавить внутри пустого свой импортированный(3D модель)? Создал пустой объект, ему добавил свойство mesh, туда добавил модель. Не показывает. Пробовал туда добавить цилиндр, сферу и тд, тоже не показывает

Comment: Что то получилось - добавил свойство Mesh Renderer и объект появился но стал плоским и фиолетовым. Пожалуйста, объясни пошагово. Вот есть 3D модель, в ней внутри два света и непосредственно сама модель. Вот я создал пустой объект GameObject -> Create Empty. Он создался тоже с не таким передом и задом каким надо. Как поменять их местами? Просто развернуть? А что дальше? Как именно вставить туда эту 3D модель?

Comment: Блин не думал что так трудно объясняю. Создайте пустой объект на сцене. Теперь бросьте на сцену вашу модельку. Поместите ее как вложенный объект внутрь пустого, и там разворачивайте как именно вам нужно, хоть вверх ногами... Извините что так долго отвечал, был в отпуске.